# Trying to get location coordinates in a tizen wearable web app

Tags: javascript, gps, geolocation, tizen

Hello I am new to tizen but am trying to make a web app for the gear s smartwatch. Is it possible to get the gps coordinates in a wearable web app? I have seen many try but most if not all have either failed or not posted what they did to get it working.

Here is the tutorial I followed, it works in firefox browser but says "User denied the request for Geolocation" in tizen preview.. -

https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tutorials/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/location/geolocation-api-specification?langredirect=1#Retrieving_Location_Info

Comment: Have you tried it on emulator or real gear s ?

Comment: Have you added these 
Privilege: http://tizen.org/privilege/location
Required feature:

    http://tizen.org/feature/location.gps

Comment: Yes I have those priveleges, and im trying it with the emulator

Comment: Did it work on Emulator ?

Comment: No it says user denied request

Comment: Please update your question by adding the full js code you used ...